# Problem with MouseMove event, launched when the content of control beneath is moved with arrow keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, mouse

My `UserControl` is a kind of a container that has a set of controls inside. One of the UI behaviours I designed is that the move over nested control makes it selected for some keyboard triggered actions.

The other way of setting up the nested control that is targeted to receive keyboard input is with arrow keys that change focus to certain control within my `UserControl`.

The problem is that in most cases my `UserControl` has scrollbars and switching between its elements with arrow keys causes contents to move. Because of that movement it seems that mousemove event is launched also when the mouse arrow stands still, but its over my usercontrol. In the end, the wrong nested control is being selected.

I tried to set a boolean flag to temporary lock the actions of mousemove event while the arrow keys handling function is launched, but it seems to not to work at all.

Does anybody have an idea how to prevent that unwanted triggering of mousemove event and avoid the problems it causes?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to impose a different focus model to the one built into windows (i.e. you seem to want a "focus the control under the mouse cursor"). Is there a reason to break conventional user expectations so badly? Also, although the mouse hasn't physically moved, logically it has - it's now positioned over a different part of the control, so of course the mouse move event occurs.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever Oh there is no suprise in fact that move of control leads to mouse event when cursor is over that particular control. The question is how i can avoid/temporary disable in efficient way event launching or detect such case of mouse move and prevent code from execution. Mouse move doesnt cause focus!, just selects in non visible way control for some actions, arrow keys also causes selection and move of containercontrol content to scroll to newly selected control,if its out of view, i achieve it using focus().Its designed this way and I stick to spec.as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some debugging/experiments and it appears that though mouse stays still over controll the **MouseMove** is actually called frequently and not only when control move is caused by some UI behaviour (scrolling of parent controll called using keyboard).

It also seems like it is called twice every single second (but probably only when application is launched form VS during debug session?), the calls are separated by few hundred parts of seconds and for now i couldnt determine what causes those.

Solution (maybe not only, and not the best) is to store last position of cursor and compare it inside event to check if mouse was really moved from last **MouseMove** call. I achieved it using `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` because position from **MouseEventArgs** will be diffrent depending on circumstances but still will be inconclusive to determine if mouse cursor was moved.

```
    Point lastCursorPosition = new Point();

    private void panelPictures_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position != lastCursorPosition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mouse moved");
            lastCursorPosition = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mouse in place");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You asked about focusing on the control, and gave an answer for how to ignore "samePos" events...